# Algorithm that lowers a yearly payment each month

Tags: javascript, function

I have tried to get a system that would automatically lower the price each month, So in December you pay 1/12 of the price and in February you pay 11/12 and so on.

But I can't seem to work it out so I'm here to ask for help :)

```
function calcTotalPrice(){
    var month = new Array();
        month[0] = "January";
        month[1] = "February";
        month[2] = "March";
        month[3] = "April";
        month[4] = "May";
        month[5] = "June";
        month[6] = "July";
        month[7] = "August";
        month[8] = "September";
        month[9] = "October";
        month[10] = "November";
        month[11] = "December";

    var d = new Date();
    var n = month[d.getMonth()];
    // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
    var yearPrijs = 12.5;
    var membership = new Array();
    if (month[0]){
        membership[0] = yearPrice;
    }
    else{
        for(i = 0;i < month.length; i++){
            yearPrice = yearPrice*0.9167;
            membership[i] = yearPrice;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `12.5 - (new Date().getMonth() * 0.9167)`?

Comment: `yearPrice*0.9167` should be `yearPrice = yearPrice*0.9167`

Comment: `if (month[0])` is **always** going to be true....

Comment: General advice: use a debugger and concentrate on the desired outcome of each step. This way you should see the discrepancies quickly. Works also without a debugger, if you are familiar with the programming language.

Comment: @Liam What could i do to make it better, I'm not great at Javascript myself.

Comment: @simon Thanks for the advise i just dont know how the de-bugger works.

Comment: I'm not sure the requirement is clear?  You want to reduce the price each month BUT increase the amount they pay 1/12, 2/12, 3/12 etc of the new monthly price?  So, for the first month, for an initial 100, they pay 100/12 = 8.33.  For the second month, 100 is reduced to 91.67 and they pay 91.67 * 2/12 = 15.28.  For the third month, 91.67 is reduced to 84.03 and they pay 84.03 * 3/12 = 21.01 and so on.  OR, are they just paying the 100, 91.67, 84.03 etc etc?

Comment: Seems to me that it's just @nbokmans equation. That's about it, no?

Comment: I wasn't sure.  "lower the price each month" plus "pay 1/12 of the price and in February you pay 11/12" may or may not mean the same thing?

Comment: @ATD Basiclly people have to pay 12,50 each year so in Januari the full price so i could also do 12,50 / 12*month but i have no clue how to implement it in to the code

So 12,50 in january then 11,45 in february

Comment: @nbokmans How would i implemt it in to my code? Im still trying to learn javascript so im not sure were to add this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK @jssse, I think I get what's required.

```js
let startDate = new Date();
let startPrice = 12.5;

// Copy the date/price for use in the loop
let newDate = startDate;
let newPrice = startPrice;

let monthly = [];
let totalPrice = 0;

let month = new Array();
  month[0] = "January";
  month[1] = "February";
  month[2] = "March";
  month[3] = "April";
  month[4] = "May";
  month[5] = "June";
  month[6] = "July";
  month[7] = "August";
  month[8] = "September";
  month[9] = "October";
  month[10] = "November";
  month[11] = "December";


// Uncomment either:

// To start from this month, if it is January, or January next year if not
// So, for September 2020, this will be January 2021

//let startMonth = newDate.getMonth();
//if (startMonth != 0) {
//  newDate = new Date(newDate.setMonth(12));
//}

// OR:
// To start from January this year, no matter what month we are in
// so, for September 2020, this will be January 2020

newDate = new Date(newDate.setMonth(0));



for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  newPrice = Math.round(newPrice * 100)/100;
  monthly.push({"Month": month[newDate.getMonth()], "Cost": newPrice});
  totalPrice += newPrice;
  // create the new date/price for next month
  //newPrice = newPrice - (newPrice * (1 / 12));
  newPrice = newPrice - (startPrice / 12);
  let m = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
  newDate = new Date(newDate.setMonth(m));
}
console.table(monthly);
console.log(totalPrice);
```

For things like this, it's often easiest to construct something in a spreadsheet - once you have the results you want, you then have the formula that you can convert into javascript code.  In this case, it's just a case of reducing the amount by 1/12 each month - but only after the first month has been dealt with (exactly as you would in a spreadsheet - you only put the formula on the second row onwards).

Normally, when outputting an array, I would use console.table(arrayname) - but that doesn't seem to work in snippets, so I've used console.log instead, so you may have to copy the code into your own html file to see the array values.

Comment: Hey, Thanks man for your time but this is not what im looking for. Let me explain better,

Each year, Starting for January you have a price which this year is 12.50, 


```
price = 12,50
january = price
febuary =  price/12*11
March = price/12*10
and so on.
```

Comment: Wasn't that the commented out bit of my code - the line that starts "// OR..." ?  Uncomment that line and comment out the line above that starts "newPrice ="  That reduces the price by 1/12 of the original price each month.  The code as it stands would give you 12.50, 11.46, 10.51, 9.63, 8.83, 8.09, 7.42, 6.80, 6.23, 5.71, 5.23 and 4.70.  Switching the codes lines, you get: 12.50, 11.46, 10.42, 9.38, 8.34, 7.30, 6.26, 5.22, 4.18, 3.14, 2.10 and 1.06.  If neither of these are correct, then I have no idea what your formula is!

Comment: You might find it easier to construct something in a spreadsheet first.  Put the initial value in A1, then add in a formula in B1 that calculates the next month's value based on the A1 value.  Copy that down to complete a year and check the results.  If the results are what you need, then include the formula from B1 in your code explaining that this is the formula you want to turn into javascript code.  That way, as long as we understand spreadsheet formulas, we can see what you want to achieve.

Comment: I appricate the Tips, Now there is only one thing left to do and that is, making it that the full price is only at january and not the month that we are in. I think i have to change this *month[newDate.getMonth()* in to *Array(months)* Or do i have to change the *newDate* to january?

Comment: Will the pricing always start from January?  So, for this month, September 2020, you want to start in January 2021 but if it were being run in January 2021, then keep that?  OR, do you want to go back to January 2020 for this month?

Comment: Yes pricing should start from January 2020

Comment: OK - I've updated the code.  You have two choices - one for January 2020 and the other for January 2021.  For the first, (which is the active code), the month is just set to 0 (=January) no matter what month we are in.  For the second, (which is commented out), the month is set to 12 if the month is not currently 0 (ie, we are in any month other than January) which sets it as January next year.

Comment: Such a legend <3 Thanks mate i appricate it <3

Comment: So, it's all working ok now?  Can we close this question? :)

Comment: All fixed :D how do i close it?

Comment: No idea - I've never asked a question!  I had assumed that there would be a button that only you could see.  I think that, at the very least, you need to click the up-arrow button next to my code - that way the question on any listing will show a solid green box which indicates that you have accepted an answer.  Maybe that's all you need to do - I'm not entirely sure!  Have a look to see if there are any other buttons next to my code - if not, just click the up button

Comment: :) I see you've found whatever is needed to tick my code as ok.